# Disable error from database

Tags: php, yii, message

I have a registration form, where I do validation which is not working like I want. The user chooses their birth date but, if they choose a date that does not exist, ex. 2016-02-31 an SQL error will occur:

> **Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException**
>
> **SQLSTATE[23000]:** Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
> 'BirthDate' cannot be null The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO
> `urUser` (`Login`, `Email`, `RulesAccept`, `Rel_Sex`, `Name`,
> `BirthDate`, `Surname`, `PasswordHash`, `auth_key`, `status`,
> `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('ania', 'ania@wp.pl', 1, 2,
> 'Ania', NULL, 'Kowalska',
> '$2y$13$3N.16FSerWx6IEbT1OZjBOReMeiWslCj..fhqDvgePxqg3jZhdanG',
> 'mMZ-MyAGRSdzH_VhN0qT5UEKPjiPvw3h', 10, 1453830416, 1453830416)

When I click back button (left arrow) I get this error:

> Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Incorrect date');

What can I do to disable this first error and force the page to stay for the registration form where I will have my messages displayed. I tried to implement `try`/`catch` but I don't know if that in good place to do it.

I use this function to reurn data:

```
public function getDate() {
        return $this->year . '-' . $this->month . '-' . $this->day;
    }

    public function getDbFormatedDate() {
    if (checkdate($this->month, $this->day, $this->year)){
    $dateDeadline = date_create($this->getDate());
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', Yii::t('app', 'Udało się zarejestrować'));
   return date_format($dateDeadline, 'Y-m-d');
    }
      Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Nieprawidłowa data');
      
}
```

I call to my getDbFormatedDate() in function singnup so it so hard to use there if !is_null:

```
 public function signup()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $user = new User();
            $user->Login = $this->login;
            $user->Email = $this->email;
            $user->RulesAccept=1;
            $user->Rel_Sex = $this->sex;
            $user->Name = $this->name;
            $user->BirthDate = $this->getDbFormatedDate();
            $user->Surname = $this->surname;
            $user->setPassword($this->password);
            $user->generateAuthKey();
            if ($user->save()) {
                return $user;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: can you show your rules in your User model ?

Comment: Also could be nice to see your model User.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

```
 public function signup()
 {
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->BirthDate = $this->getDbFormatedDate();

        if (is_null($user->BirthDate))
            return false;

        $user->Login = $this->login;
        $user->Email = $this->email;
        $user->RulesAccept=1;
        $user->Rel_Sex = $this->sex;
        $user->Name = $this->name;
        $user->Surname = $this->surname;
        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        if ($user->save()) {
            return $user;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Okay, you don't need an if, like so:

```
public function getDate() {
    return $this->year . '-' . $this->month . '-' . $this->day;
}

public function getDbFormatedDate() {
    if (checkdate($this->month, $this->day, $this->year)){
        $dateDeadline = date_create($this->getDate());
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', Yii::t('app', 'Udało się zarejestrować'));
        return date_format($dateDeadline, 'Y-m-d');
    }
    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Nieprawidłowa data');
    return null;
}
```

And then if you call getDbFormattedDate(), do this:

```
if (!is_null($this->getDbFormatedDate())
    // Handle your database insert
```

Comment: i know about that but now i want to know that it is possible to disable this error witch try catch for example or others tricks

Comment: Your database will not insert because your constraint `not null`. All you need is validation of the input. Don't use try/catch for validation.

Comment: i asked about disable this error from some tricks i know that this my input shouldnt be empty. I dont know why in other form with the same datatable this error not show i see only my error from Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Incorrect date') and i stay at the same page

Comment: problem is that i crashed my data in 3 inputs(like in facebook registration month, year, day), and when user choose date which not exist this return me null. And i cant use birthdate required in rules becouse i havent this value in my form i have day, year and month which i Picking up the pieces to BirthDay in my base

Comment: the same i cant use in rules my year,day ad month require becosue i have error there is not year class. How can i bypass this?

Comment: yes i use this chceckdate in my function but if it return false it is null value look in my first post i actualise this i give this function getDate and second function

Comment: but when checkdate return false it give me null value i dont know what can i do to disable this db error becosue this false  give me null. That is my first question how can i bypass this becouse i think i can do nothing in my rules. Maybe there is a method that does not dispose of an error from the base and become a form page

Comment: hmm can u write this piece of function?

Comment: i am begginier and i dont know what i should write this in me else in function getDbFormatedDate()?? or somwhere in function save?

Comment: that's what I meant, how can stop the saving what should i write to my else in my function?

Comment: i edited my first post too so i use my function in signup() where is soo hard to use this if which u send to me

Comment: Perfect! I'm happy for you! Please mark the right answer ;-)